# Chrome will not cache javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I'm trying to get Chrome to cache my Javascript (the HTML includes a version number as a cache buster). So the idea is that if the version does not change I shouldn't need to reload 1MiB of Javascript but Chrome always seems to reload it anyway. I think I have the server returning the correct headers.

My html looks like:

```
<script type="application/javascript" async src="/index.js?version=123"></script>
```

Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: application/javascript
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 15:09:36 GMT
Vary: Origin
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 00:52:23 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I have the "disable Cache" un-selected in the Network tab and in the devTools settings I've un-selected "Disable cache (when devTools is running)

I can see that my fonts are cached in the network tab of devTools but my index.js still loads all 1MiB

Comment: please add any additional details into your original question by [edit]ing

Comment: Is this problem only in Chrome?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you need to specify a max-age directive in your Cache-Control header. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

Comment: I added max-age but I'm still seeing it not pick the file up from cache
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be because I'm using https but my dev box server doesn't have a certificate. If I disable https and use http it does cache the Javascript.